# What causes the same data to have different sizes in two different SQL server databases?

Tags: sql-server, database, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I have a table with 339 million rows and twenty-one columns of which seventeen are varchar(100) types, two are integer types and one is a float and a DateTime type. It is in an Azure SQL server database. The table has no indices and only the primary key constraint. I aim to copy this table to a new database and delete the old one. My approach to this problem is to save the data on Delta Lake and use an Azure Data Factory pipeline to save it to the new database. I have used this approach several times before for migrating tables to new databases.

However, I am met with a strange problem. In the old database, the table is about 80Gb in total. Yet on the new database, it takes only 54% of the data (182 million rows) to fill 276Gb. There is no DBA in my team to help me with this matter. What could, possibly, be causing this? I hope I have included all the information that could help with this issue.

Comment: Almost sure there is a table defragmentation on the old DB

Comment: Are you rebuilding the clustered index after the data is inserted?

Comment: Are you using the exact same data types in the new table? Including column collations?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - Yes, I am using exactly the same table definition.

Comment: The question belongs to DB Administration, so please try posting it in DBA Exchange rather than in Stack Overflow.